# Start loop after certain element in list is reached

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement, for-loop, break

How do I start executing code in a for loop after a certain element in the list has been reached. I've got something that works, but is there a more pythonic or faster way of doing this?

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] 
condition = 0

for i in list:
    if i == 'c' or condition == 1:
        condition = 1
        print i
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would to be to iterate over a generator combining `dropwhile` and `islice`:

```
from itertools import dropwhile, islice

data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] 
for after in islice(dropwhile(lambda L: L != 'c', data), 1, None):
    print after
```

If you want including then drop the `islice`.

Answer (score 1):

A little simplified code:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] 

start_index = lst.index('c')
for i in lst[start_index:]:
    print i
```

Comment: Some points worth noting: 1) If the element doesn't exist, you'll get an `IndexError`, 2) This creates a new list that's iterated over..., 3) It's less generic as it'll only work with items that support indexing and slicing... Otherwise - it works for the OP so all's good.